# How can I use meta-tags gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm using meta-tags gem for rails.

and I set meta tags below.

***application.html.erb***

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= display_meta_tags({
:title => "" ,
:site => t('site') ,
:description => '',
:keywords => '',
:viewport => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" ,
:reverse => true
})%>
```

and here is view file.

***view.erb***

```
<% set_meta_tags 
    title '@hoge.title',
    description '#{@hoge.neme} is awesome'
 %>
```

It cause syntax error.
How can I write proper way?

Comment: There's a great example for how the meta-tags gem can be nicely use here: http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/easy-seo-metatags-with-rails-4/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (It has comprehensive solution on how to use meta-tags with rails 4 app) http://www.buggingcode.com/adding-meta-tags-in-rails-4-app-for-each-post-in-views

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of this syntax error you should pass the `title` and `description` to `set_meta_tags` as a hash, just like you did for `display_meta_tag`. More than one syntax version will work, you can read more about hash syntax http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html

```
<% set_meta_tags({
    :title => '@hoge.title',
    :description => '#{@hoge.neme} is awesome'
 })%>
```

or

```
<% set_meta_tags({ 
    title: '@hoge.title',
    description: '#{@hoge.neme} is awesome'
})%>
```